# VB.Net passing/calling a variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How do I pass a value over to a module/function. Whenever I search here or Google I am getting code for C# rather than VB.net

I want to be able to click on a button and pass a value to a module and action it. Each button has a value 1,2,3,4 etc... and they pass back to make a panel visible=true/false.

i.e. I want to say the below but when I click btnShow1 I want to pass this as a value to a function and hide/show the panel I am talking about.

Current code

```
 Protected Sub btnShowQ1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShowQ1.Click

        If panel1.Visible = True Then
            panel1.Visible = False
        Else
            panel1.Visible = True
        End If

    End Sub
```

Guess code

```
 'Protected Sub btnShowQ1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShowQ1.Click
             vpanel = btnShowQ1.value
        Call fncPanel(vpanel as string) as string

    End Sub
```

Then somewhere - I guess in App_code I create function.vb

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class ciFunctions
    Public Function fncPanel(vPanel as string)as string
            If (vPanel).visible = False then
                (vPanel).visible = true
            Else
                (vPanel).visible = false
             End IF 
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Lazy answer, you can always take your sample code and run it through a free code converter to see the vb.net:  http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: @rie819 not such a good idea. 

OP, what exactly do you want to do ? It's not clear at all. You say you want to pass **this** as a value. what is **this** ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the button's CommandArgument property to the panel number to which it shows or hides:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show/Hide" CommandArgument="1" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Show/Hide" CommandArgument="2" />
```

On the button click event:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, ...
    ' get the button which triggers this event
    Dim thisButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button) 

    ' construct the panel name to toggle visibility from the button's CommandArgument property
    Dim panelName as String = "panel" & thisButton.CommandArgument

    ' call the function, passing the panel name and the reference to current page
    TogglePanel(Me, panelName)
End Sub
```

You can add all the buttons click event handler to this sub by adding them to the Handles... list as above. Therefore you don't have to create event handler for each buttons on the page. Just one to handle them all.

Create the function to toggle visibility:

```
Sub TogglePanel(pg As Page, panelName As String)
    ' get the panel control on the page
    Dim panel As Panel = DirectCast(pg.FindControl(panelName), Panel)

    ' toggle its visibility
    panel.Visible = Not panel.Visible
End Sub
```

The `pg` parameter is required if you put this function in a class other than the page it runs on or in a module. If the function sit in the same page class, then pg is not required.

Comment: I get error "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code. ON the panel.Visible = Not.panel.Visible seciton. My (well your code:)

Comment: That error means the panelName value could not be found on your page. you have to modify the line `Dim panelName as String = "panel" & thisButton.CommandArgument` accordingly so that it will reflect the name of your panel.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add a parameter of type Panel to the sub, and in the btnShow event, pass the item.

```
Public Sub ChangePanelVis(panel as Panel)
    If panel.Visible then
        panel.Visible = True
    Else
        panel.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub btnShowQ1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShowQ1.Click
    ChangePanelVis(panel1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @APrough the line `'ChangePanelVis(panel1)'` comes up with an error if I put the code in function.vb i.e.'Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

    Public Class Functions
        Public Sub ChangePanelVis(panel As Panel)
            If panel.Visible Then
                panel.Visible = True
            Else
                panel.Visible = True
            End If
        End Sub
    
    End Class
    ' 

but works on the same page. How can I pass it outside the page and in a *vb page the way to go?

Comment: Also can I pass the button value through to get the text on the button to change. I have tried as a string but that errors under the part tha t sasy textBtn.text  Public Sub ChangePanelVis(panel As Panel, textBtn As String)
        If panel.Visible = True Then
            panel.Visible = False
            textBtn.text = "+Show Answers"
        Else
            panel.Visible = True
            textBtn.text = "-Hide Answers"
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: If the sub is in the same page, then this will work.  If it is on another page, then see ajakblackgoat's answer.  He includes the functionality on using Page.  As for the textbox text, just include another parameter of Button and set the text of that to what you want.